# Group DataFrame by entries X amount of time from each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to group together the entries in which the timestamp difference between one and the other is X amount of seconds or less than then average the value for each of them for each of the devices. In the following example I have a Data Frame with this data and I need to group by device with entries between 60 seconds from each other.

```
              Device            Timestamp  Value
0  30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b  10/26/2015 22:50:15     34
1  30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b  10/26/2015 22:50:46     34
2  c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd  10/26/2015 22:50:50     33
3  c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd  10/26/2015 22:50:51     32
4  30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b  10/26/2015 22:51:15     34
5  30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b  10/26/2015 22:51:47     32
6  c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd  10/26/2015 22:52:38     38
7  30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b  10/26/2015 22:54:46     34
```

This should be the resulting DataFrame

```
              Device           First_seen            Last_seen Average_value
0  30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b  10/26/2015 22:50:15  10/26/2015 22:51:47          33,5
1  c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd  10/26/2015 22:50:50  10/26/2015 22:50:51          32,5
2  c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd  10/26/2015 22:52:38  10/26/2015 22:52:38            38
3  30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b  10/26/2015 22:54:46  10/26/2015 22:54:46            34
```

I have been trying to use timeGrouper but I haven’t been able to get to a working solution. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
diffs = df.groupby(['Device'])['Timestamp'].diff()
# In [39]: diffs
# Out[39]: 
# 0        NaT
# 1   00:00:31
# 2        NaT
# 3   00:00:01
# 4   00:00:29
# 5   00:00:32
# 6   00:01:47
# 7   00:02:59
# dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

to calculate the difference between successive timestamps for each device group.
Note that this relies on the Timestamps being in sorted order (at least within each `Device` group). If it isn't you could of course sort the rows by `Timestamp` first, (e.g. `df = df.sort('Timestamp')`)

Then create a boolean mask to find when the diff is more than 60 seconds:

```
df['gap'] = diffs > pd.Timedelta(seconds=60)
# In [42]: df['gap']
# Out[42]: 
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2    False
# 3    False
# 4    False
# 5    False
# 6     True
# 7     True
# Name: gap, dtype: bool
```

For each device, we can use `cumsum` to compute the cumulative sum of `df['gap']`.

```
df['group'] = df.groupby(['Device'])['gap'].cumsum()
# In [45]: df['group']
# Out[45]: 
# 0    0
# 1    0
# 2    0
# 3    0
# 4    0
# 5    0
# 6    1
# 7    1
# Name: group, dtype: int64
```

Since False is treated as 0 and True is treated as 1, the cumulative sum in effect numbers the rows within each device-group which belong to the same gap-group.

Now we can groupby both the `Device` and `group` columns and find the first and last `Timestamp` and the mean `Value` within each group:

```
result = df.groupby(['Device', 'group']).agg(
             {'Timestamp': ['first','last'], 'Value':'mean'}):

#                                   Timestamp                     Value
#                                       first                last  mean
# Device            group                                              
# 30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b 0     2015-10-26 22:50:15 2015-10-26 22:51:47  33.5
#                   1     2015-10-26 22:54:46 2015-10-26 22:54:46  34.0
# c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd 0     2015-10-26 22:50:50 2015-10-26 22:50:51  32.5
#                   1     2015-10-26 22:52:38 2015-10-26 22:52:38  38.0
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Device': {0: '30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b',
                1: '30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b',
                2: 'c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd',
                3: 'c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd',
                4: '30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b',
                5: '30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b',
                6: 'c0:ee:fb:35:ec:cd',
                7: '30:8c:fb:a4:b9:8b'},
     'Timestamp': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 22:50:15'),
                   1: pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 22:50:46'),
                   2: pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 22:50:50'),
                   3: pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 22:50:51'),
                   4: pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 22:51:15'),
                   5: pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 22:51:47'),
                   6: pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 22:52:38'),
                   7: pd.Timestamp('2015-10-26 22:54:46')},
     'Value': {0: 34, 1: 34, 2: 33, 3: 32, 4: 34, 5: 32, 6: 38, 7: 34}})

diffs = df.groupby(['Device'])['Timestamp'].diff()
df['gap'] = diffs > pd.Timedelta(seconds=60)
df['group'] = df.groupby(['Device'])['gap'].cumsum()
result = df.groupby(['Device', 'group']).agg({'Timestamp': ['first','last'], 'Value':'mean'})
print(result)
```

Comment: Works great! I already tried and is the exact result i was looking for, thank you for the approach